# GPGPU for 3d math

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am reading a lot about gpgpu and I am currently learning OpenGL. Now that I have to write all math by myself (or use an existing 3rd party library) I had the idea of using the gpu instead of the cpu for creating my own math library. (matrices vectors etc)

But I didn't found any 3d math library which utilizes the gpu.

Is there a specific reason?

Maybe the CPU is better at those tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how many vectors or matrices you want to work on at a time, and whether you want to draw the results or not.

GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language) already has a maths library built in. It has functions and operators for matrix maths, transpose, inverse; vector dot and cross products; multiplying a vector by a matrix, etc.

When you're drawing geometry or whatever with OpenGL, you use these built-in functions in your shaders on the GPU. No point in a 3d math library replicating what is already there.

If you want to do small scale vector/matrix maths without drawing anything, for instance a ray - plane intersection test, then the CPU is better. Copying the values to the GPU and copying the result back would take much longer than just doing the math on the CPU. (Even if the GPU were actually faster - typical speeds today are 2Ghz+ for CPU, < 1Ghz for GPU.) This is why math libraries just use the CPU.

If you want to do "industrial scale" matrix/vector math without drawing, then yes it is worth considering the GPU. (This is why CUDA and OpenCL exist.) With a modern version of OpenGL that supports transform feedback and texture buffer objects (usually V3+) you can do maths on hundreds to thousands of matrices/vectors on the GPU, and OpenGL 4.3 makes it even easier with compute shaders. It isn't quite as convenient or efficient as CUDA/OpenCL, but if you already know OpenGL it is much easier.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look for CUDA thrust as a starting point. I think GPU's will be good for this task. SIMD on CPU's can be something to look into as well but will not give as much parallelism as you'd be hoping for .

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be more open than CUDA. I just found ViennaCL which looks promising. But I also saw that I have to move the memory around. Would this really give me a performance increase for something as trivial as a matrix or vector? Because I am a little bit scared that once I move the memory to the gpu, the cpu solution would already be finished.

Comment: depends on the size of your data as well. Remember you'd be probably doing a cudaMemCpy or some other function to transfer data between the CPU and GPU , so your data set must be big enough to justify the SIMT computation gain you get from CUDA. Also think of small things like performance benefits of Array of Structs or Structs of Arrays for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [arrayfire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/). It supports up to 4 dimensions and has a lot of support for commonly used functions. Currently only cuda is supported, but opencl support will be added shortly with the same interface (I work at Accelereyes, so I know this).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of operations do you want to do? You can use the OpenCL built-in float4 and its default operators (+,-,*,/, dot, sqrt) for Vector3 or Vector4. You can easily extend this with Quaternions and Matrices, that's what we did.

See http://github.com/erwincoumans/experiments

The code can help you learning OpenCL and also OpenGL and OpenCL-OpenGL interop.

My github repository contains simple 3d math functions for quaternions, 3d vectors and 3x3 matrices for the OpenCL version of our 3D Bullet game physics library. It also has a fast radix sort, prefix scan, collision detection algorithms and rigid body dynamics, 100% running on GPU. It runs on NVIDIA, AMD,Intel Windows & Mac OSX.
https://github.com/erwincoumans/experiments/blob/master/opencl/primitives/AdlPrimitives/Math/MathCL.h